# Python Pandas: How to subtract values in two non-consecutive rows in a specific column of a dataframe from one another

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to populate the values in a new column in a Pandas df by subtracting the value of two non-consecutive rows in a different column within the same df.  I can do it, so long as the df does not have a column with dates in it.  But if it does have a column with dates then pandas throws an error.

Assume the following dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 55, 9], [10, 99, 19], [27, 38, 29], [39, 10, 72]]),
                   columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
df['Date'] = ['2020-01-02', '2020-01-05', '2020-06-10', '2020-08-05', '2020-09-01', '2020-10-29']
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

df['d'] = ''
df = df[['Date', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd']]
```

This gives me a df that looks like this:

```
    Date        a   b   c   d
0   2020-01-02  1   2   3   
1   2020-01-05  4   5   6   
2   2020-06-10  7   55  9   
3   2020-08-05  10  99  19  
4   2020-09-01  27  38  29  
5   2020-10-29  39  10  72
```

I am trying to create a new column 'd' that, for each row, subtracts the value in column 'b' two rows below from the row in question.  For instance, the value in row [0], column ['d'] would be calculated as df.loc[2]['b'] - df.loc[0]['b'].

What I'm trying (which doesn't work) is:

```
for i in range(len(df)-2):
    df.loc[i]['d'] = df.loc[i+2]['b'] - df.loc[i]['b']
```

I can get this to work if I have no date in the df.  But when I add a column with dates, it throws an error message saying

```
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame
```

I can't figure out why a date column causes the df to be unable to do math on columns with only int64 data.  I've tried searching this site and just can't seem to solve the problem.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you please show us the expected dataframe?

Comment: There are better ways to do this but your issue with the current approach is chained assignment `][`, So your changes don't stick because you're setting the values on the copy. You should use the two indexers in `.loc`, not a chain: `df.loc[i, 'd'] = df.loc[i+2, 'b'] - df.loc[i, 'b']`

Comment: Thanks, @ALollz.  This makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it in vectorized form using `shift` (which is considerably faster than using loops):

```
df['d'] = df['b'].shift(-2) - df['b']
df
```

Output:

```
        Date   a   b   c     d
0 2020-01-02   1   2   3  53.0
1 2020-01-05   4   5   6  94.0
2 2020-06-10   7  55   9 -17.0
3 2020-08-05  10  99  19 -89.0
4 2020-09-01  27  38  29   NaN
5 2020-10-29  39  10  72   NaN
```

Comment: Thanks @perl!!  It works!  I'll definitely use your method going forward, but do you know why my method stopped working when I added a date?  It says I am creating a slice of a df, but I have no idea how I am doing so just by adding a date column.

Comment: How do you mean 'added a date'? I think @ALollz gave a good explanation of why your original approach failed (posted as a comment to your original post)

Comment: Thanks, @perl.  I missed that comment - definitely makes more sense now.  Thanks again for your fantastic solution!

Comment: Also `df['b'].diff(-2)`